# What URI should be returned in HTTP Location header in REST response, if I have two URIs for the same resource?

Tags: rest, http

Let's say I am modeling blogging REST API which has resources `Blog`, `Post` and `Comment`.
Then I add following URIs for `Blog` and `Post` resources:

```
/api/blogs
/api/blogs/{blogId}
/api/blogs/{blogId}/posts
```

and since deep nesting should be avoided I create separate endpoint for all `Post`s in order to get their Comment`s:

```
/api/posts
/api/posts/{postId}
/api/posts/{postId}/comments
```

Now, if I implement `POST` action that creates a new `Post` for a specific `Blog` on `/api/blogs/{blogId}/posts` endpoint, should I set `Location` header value in response to:

`/api/blogs/{blogId}/posts/123`

or

`/api/posts/123`

?

In either case I can GET the same resource, but is there some preference, according to REST style, which should be returned to client after successful `POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If one or more resources has been created on the origin server as a result of successfully processing a POST request, the origin server SHOULD send a 201 (Created) response containing a Location header field that provides an identifier for the primary resource created (Section 7.1.2) and a representation that describes the status of the request while referring to the new resource(s). -- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)

Which resource is the "primary resource"?  That's up to you - priority of the resources is going to depend on your resource model, and REST / HTTP do not care what model you use.

In effect, it comes down to "which URI do you want to see in your access logs?"

Comment: Right now I don't have any preferences for what I'd like to see in logs, do you have any suggestion how to make this decision? It seems to me that `/api/blogs/{blogId}/posts/123` might be better because I will immediately see to which Blog this Post belongs, but I am not sure if this will be relevant to me. So, beside access logs, is there any other criteria on how to choose "primary resource" URI?